# Porting "Quartz Scheduler .NET" to Windows Azure -> Web apps. Not to Windows Azure VM

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, quartz.net

I'm using the Quartz Enterprise Scheduler .NET for my jobs. Can I port my console application wrapped on the Quartz into Windows Azure Web App? I just need to install "Windows Service" and configure some port to listen on Azure. I don't want to use Windows Azure VM because I don't want to configure server and install updates, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of Web Apps as a managed IIS instance - you can't access the host OS at all.  So no installing things or configuring ports.

You might take a look at [Cloud Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/cloud-services/) which are kind of a hybrid of Web Apps and VMs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Web Jobs, which will in the same context of Azure Web App. It accepts console application and also .sh, .js and other formats. Probably you won't need to change almost nothing in your code.